# IOS UITableview how to take action after table animations complete

Tags: ios, animation, tableview, uitableview

How can I cause action to be taken upon completion of a UITableview's animation?

I'm attempting to shrink a UITableview cell and remove a subview of the cell that's not visible after the shrinkage.  To shrink the cell, I'm calling [tableview beginUpdates] and [tableview endUpdates], and changing the height of the cell as returned by theheightForRowAtIndexPath datasource method of the UITableview.

The challenge is, i need the tableview to complete shrinking so the subview is out of sight before I can remove the subview. if I put the code to remove the subview from the cell right after (or before or between) the to call [tableview endUpdates] then the subview is removed too soon (it doesn't wait for the animation) and it looks funny.

My thought is i'd like to be able to setup a callback that runs upon completion of the animation, and remove the subView in the callback

Comment: the best thing I've found so far is running performSelector on a short time delay:     

  [self performSelector:@selector(removeSubmenuViewFromCellView) withObject:nil afterDelay:.3];

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about this?

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // animation has finished
}];

[tableView beginUpdates];
// shrink the cells
[tableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rudolf.  I'm not sure when I'll have the chance to review this, as it's been awhile since I've worked on this question.  However if someone else can comment that this is a good solution, or I get to try it out, I'll mark it as the answer. In the meanwhile, +1.

Comment: This is a good solution. Just worked for me where I needed code to run only after a table row had animated away.

Answer (score -4):

Try Using NSNotifications class. Post Notifications when something is about to happen, and later after something has happened. You can use a bool in the same notification method to toggle between 'about to happen' and 'has happened'.

Comment: (pardon if this comment is a duplicate) My understanding is that the one UITableview notification that exists is not related to this, so registering for it wouldn't help.  As far as creating the notification myself, I'd want the notification to be posted right after the tableview finishes it's animation, but like the original problem states, i don't know of a way to have my code run (to post a notification or otherwise) at that point.

Comment: Posting a notification is very simple.. Just check the apple docs for the same. Clear and precise explanation with example is provided. All the best with your task.

Comment: I'm just saying that notifications would not be useful in this situation :)  Thanks for all the feedback though!